# How would I write a function that finds all occurrences of a specific value in a list -- continues on

Tags: python

and records--in a separate list--these occurrences in terms of the indices where they were found. 
For example `find_all([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2], 2)` returns `[1, 5]`. `find_all([1, 2, 3], 0)` returns `[ ]`.

I'm totally new to python and this question is stumping me on my first homework. I need to

take 2 arguments: a list of items, and a single element to search for in the list
returns 1 list: a list of indices into the input list that correspond to elements in the input list that match what we were looking for

not sure

Comment: Check list methods (`list.index` might be useful here)

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you share that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Method using list comprehension

```
def find_all(l, value):
  return [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v == value]

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2]
print(find_all(mylist, 2)) # [1, 5]
```

Use this method since list.index only returns the first match
and you want them all

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
def find_all(input_list, search_value):
    result = []
    for idx, num in enumerate(input_list):
         if num == search_value:
             result.append(idx)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the tutorials available on the internet to learn the Python Basics.

https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument

```
def find_all(list, num):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if (list[i] == num):
            newlist.append(i)
    return newlist

list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 2]
mylist = find_all(list, 2)
print mylist
```

Hope this helps.